# GCP App Engine and Cloud Build: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js'

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, app.yaml

**TLDR:** Sorry for the longest question in history, but I hope this is comprehensive for any users having a similar problem. My app deploys successfully from cloud shell to my domain; however, when I try cloud build, I get
`Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js'`
The error likely has to due with my build handlers in the app.yaml, or something to do with my cloudbuild.yaml.

Solution: use the right handlers in app.yaml standard and properly set up your cloudbuild.yaml

I am having trouble using App Engine and Cloud Build together. I am using Cloud Build to set up CICD with my Github repo. I think the issue is due to the fact that I have been not been deploying the production build to app engine. I was able to successfully deploy manually (dev version) with:

`gcloud app deploy`

Now, I am having trouble with my Cloud Build. In particular, I am trying to run flex environment, but I keep getting "Neither "start" in the "scripts" section of "package.json" nor the "server.js" file were found." But my package.json has a startup script?

I also tried standard environment instead of flex, but I couldn't get the handlers figured out. I tried dozens of examples. I have included the standard environment app.yaml so you can see it.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "flier-mapper",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/storage": "^0.8.4",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.7.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "emailjs-com": "^3.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-pricing-table": "^0.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-tabs": "^3.2.3",
    "stripe": "^8.188.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's my cloudbuild.yaml. I also tried deleting the dir line:

```
steps:

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
  dir: 'frontend'
  args: ['install']
  timeout: "5m"

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
  dir: 'frontend'
  args: ["run", "build"]
  timeout: "5m"

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
    - "-c"
    - |
        cp app.yaml ./build
        cd build
        gcloud app deploy
  timeout: "1600s"

timeout: 60m
```

Here's my flex app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
  # The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

And here's one of the many handlers I tried with a standard environemnt:

```
runtime: nodejs14

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

handlers:
  # Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*\..+)$
  # Catch all handler to index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

**EDIT**

So, I got it to run on standard environment, which is useful for https requests. Here's my app.yaml that I got working:

```
runtime: nodejs14

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 2

handlers:

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

However, now my problem is this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
```

Which is essentially the same issue as above.

[image: 500 Server Error on GCP App Engine]

**EDIT 2**

I'm wondering if it is because now that I am running a production build I need to add the correct handlers. But as mentioned above, I have tried dozens of combinations of various answers on the internet to no avail.

Here's another standard app.yaml I tried:

```
runtime: nodejs16

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 2

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html

  - url: /
    static_dir: build
```

Is it something to do with one of my packages? If so, which one? There aren't any specials ones that I know of...

I also added this to my package.json, but it didn't do anything either:

```
"start": "PORT=8080 react-scripts start",
```

**EDIT 3**
I have tried these posts: [Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63608035/error-cannot-find-module-workspace-server-js)
[could not find module workspace/server.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740611/could-not-find-module-workspace-server-js)
[Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js' upon node js deploy on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68783153/error-cannot-find-module-workspace-server-js-upon-node-js-deploy-on-google-a)
https://medium.com/@calebmackdaven/so-you-want-to-start-using-google-cloud-ce9054e84fa8

This app.yaml built on cloud build; however, I now get a new error "The requested URL / was not found on this server.":

```
runtime: nodejs16

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 2

handlers:
  - url: /static/js/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/js/\1
    upload: build/static/js/(.*)
  - url: /static/css/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/css/\1
    upload: build/static/css/(.*)
  - url: /static/media/(.*)
    static_files: build/static/media/\1
    upload: build/static/media/(.*)
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico)$
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

My logs say:

```
Static file referenced by handler not found: build/index.html
```

**EDIT 4**
I tried a different cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:

- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

- name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']

- name: 'bash'
  args: ['gcloud app deploy']
```

However, now the error I get in my npm run build stage is :

```
Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"
```

I checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported), so I tried a different node version  14 and still got the same issue. I tried the following, but got the same error:

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

Here's my error:

```
Step #1: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
Step #1:     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
Step #1:     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
Step #1:     at module.exports (/workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
Step #1:     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
Step #1:     at /workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
Step #1:     at /workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
Step #1:     at /workspace/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
Step #1:     at /workspace/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
Step #1:     at context.callback (/workspace/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
Step #1:     at /workspace/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
Step #1:   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
Step #1:   library: 'digital envelope routines',
Step #1:   reason: 'unsupported',
Step #1:   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
Step #1: }
Step #1: 
Step #1: Node.js v17.1.0
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "node" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Why is it attempting to use Node.js v17.1.0 when I specified v16 in the app.yaml?

**EDIT 5**

I tried specifying Node v16.13.0:

```
steps:
- name: node: "16.13.0"
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

- name: node: "16.13.0"
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: bash
  args: [gcloud app deploy]
```

However, it didn't build at all:

```
Your build failed to run: failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

So I tried adding a substitution:

```
--- 
steps: 
  - 
    args: 
      - install
    entrypoint: npm
    name: "node= $_NODE_VERSION"
  - 
    args: 
      - run
      - build
    entrypoint: npm
    name: "node= $_NODE_VERSION"
  - 
    args: 
      - "gcloud app deploy"
    entrypoint: bash
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
substitutions: 
  $_NODE_VERSION: v16.13.0
```

But I got:

```
Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: invalid build: invalid build step name "node= ": could not parse reference: node=
```

And if I try node: "16.13.0", the error is similar:

```
Your build failed to run: failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Okay, that error was just due to spacing. I tried updating my cloudbuild.yaml as follows:

```
steps:
- name: node:16.13.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

- name: node:16.13.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: bash
  args: [gcloud app deploy]
```

Now I am able to build. However, now I get an issue with the gcloud command:

```
Step #2: bash: gcloud app deploy: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT 6**

I'm going in circles. My new error is the original one:

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

But at least I got the cloud build to build. So it must be my app.yaml or cloudbuild.yaml.

```
steps:
- name: node:16.13.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

- name: node:16.13.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
    - "-c"
    - |
        cp app.yaml ./build
        cd build
        gcloud app deploy
```

```
Step #2: bash: gcloud app deploy: No such file or directory
```

**Solution**
I finally got it working! I was changing directory to build, but shouldn't have been. So here are my working cloudbuild.yaml and app.yaml files:

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: node:16.13.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

- name: node:16.13.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
    - "-c"
    - |
        cp app.yaml ./build
        gcloud app deploy
```

app.yaml

```
--- 
handlers: 
  - 
    secure: always
    static_dir: build/static
    url: /static
  - 
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$
    url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
  - 
    secure: always
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
    url: .*
manual_scaling: 
  instances: 1
runtime: nodejs16
```

Comment: You may refer to the similar Stackoverflow case with the same error as you are getting.
[Google App Engine Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677834/google-app-engine-deploy-different-folder-with-the-same-app-yaml)
[Deploying app to GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111648/deploying-app-to-google-app-engine-and-want-to-start-api-and-client)
Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response! Regarding the first post, the user uses flex engine which doesn't support handlers, and I couldn't get flex running for create react app on cloud build. And regarding the second post, I'm not even using any server, just the frontend create react app, so I have my package.json in the directory from which I deploy and it has a startup script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
I finally got it working! I was changing directory to build, but shouldn't have been. So here are my working cloudbuild.yaml and app.yaml files:

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: node:16.13.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

- name: node:16.13.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run', 'build']

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
    - "-c"
    - |
        cp app.yaml ./build #not sure if this is necessary
        gcloud app deploy
```

app.yaml

```
--- 
handlers: 
  - 
    secure: always
    static_dir: build/static
    url: /static
  - 
    secure: always
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$
    url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
  - 
    secure: always
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
    url: .*
manual_scaling: 
  instances: 1
runtime: nodejs16
```